# can not open http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs with fastAPI

Tags: fastapi, openapi, python-3.10

I'm learning fastapi on win10system with python3.10, but i can't open the Swagger UI http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs
which shows 127.0.0.1 refused connection
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezrvE.png)

how can i solve it
?